# Does creating a Storyboard implies creating a xib file?

Tags: xcode, xcode6

I've created a new single view app in Xcode. LaunchScreen.xib was created in the process as well as the main storyboard.

When I add controls to the storyboard it doesn't create a new xib file for each view? I'm confused.

Can someone please clarify that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode creates xib files for each scene in your storyboard when you build the project and copies those xib files into your app bundle.

Xcode does not create xib files and add them to your project when you add views to your storyboard. Adding the xib files to the project would defeat the purpose of using storyboards, which is to have all your views in one place. Having one storyboard instead of multiple xib files in your project is a benefit, not a problem.